# How to include image gallery in php file

Tags: php, wordpress, image, themes, gallery

I am trying to include the envira gallery in php file and it's not working. Can you tell me how to include any gallery in php code so that I could display it in my template.

This is the code that i am trying to use to display galleries through my php files.

```
/* The loop */
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
        echo get_post_gallery();
    endif; 
endwhile;
```

Comment: Are you trying to display the gallery in wordpress theme??

Comment: yes, That's a custom theme that I created. In the template.php file i want to insert an image gallery plugin.

Comment: If you are using Envira Gallery plugin then you can use the shortcode for display the gallery images in your template.php file. You can check the plugin documentation file. There is mentioned the details for same.

Comment: ok ... great... :)